# Run External .exe (such as an uninstaller) from button click event

Tags: wpf, vb.net, file

I have a project based in VB.net and WPF 4. My program has a "launchpad" screen with buttons like "Play" "Demos" "User Manual" "Quit", etc.

I have an uninstall button on this menu, too. When it is clicked, I need to run the .exe file "uninst000.exe", located in my program's directory (which could be anywhere on the computer, depending on user options during installation).

How exactly do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Process.Start("C:\Path\MyApp.exe")
```

Load your path from wherever you are storing these user settings.

Comment: Hm, this caused an unknown exception. I can't test this code in debugger at this point (only in compiled version), but I'll look into it again later.

Comment: @Jason:  As long as your path is correct I can't see that happening here.  This function call virtually simulates your double-clicking a file in a Windows OS, leaving the OS to decide how to open the file.

Comment: Sweet, thank you Matt. One other question, tho...since the user can install the program (and the uninstaller, same location as the main program .exe) anywhere on the computer, how do I determine in this code what the URI is?

Comment: Well in your code if you use Application.StartupPath.  This will get you the directory of where your main executable exists.  So depending on the structure of your MSI.  If your other executable(s) that you are calling is in the same directory, just try Application.StartupPath & "\MyApp.exe"

Answer (score 2):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

`Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.ComponentModel`

Namespace MyProcessSample
    Class MyProcess
            ' Opens the Internet Explorer application.
            Public Sub OpenApplication(myFavoritesPath As String)
            ' Start Internet Explorer. Defaults to the home page.
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe")

```
        ' Display the contents of the favorites folder in the browser.
        Process.Start(myFavoritesPath)
    End Sub 'OpenApplication

    ' Opens urls and .html documents using Internet Explorer.
    Sub OpenWithArguments()
        ' url's are not considered documents. They can only be opened
        ' by passing them as arguments.
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com")

        ' Start a Web page using a browser associated with .html and .asp files.
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\myPath\myFile.htm")
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\myPath\myFile.asp")
    End Sub 'OpenWithArguments

    ' Uses the ProcessStartInfo class to start new processes,
    ' both in a minimized mode.
    Sub OpenWithStartInfo()
        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe")
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized

        Process.Start(startInfo)

        startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com"

        Process.Start(startInfo)
    End Sub 'OpenWithStartInfo

    Shared Sub Main()
        ' Get the path that stores favorite links.
        Dim myFavoritesPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites)

        Dim myProcess As New MyProcess()

        myProcess.OpenApplication(myFavoritesPath)
        myProcess.OpenWithArguments()
        myProcess.OpenWithStartInfo()
    End Sub 'Main
End Class 'MyProcess
```

End Namespace 'MyProcessSample